# com.vmware.vapi.rest.httpNotFound - Vsphere API

Tags: python, django, curl, vsphere

I am trying to get my Vsphere version through API for program I am building. The thing is I keep receiving this error even though it worked previously. It stopped working now.

Here is the command I run, but in Python django:

```
curl -H "vmware-api-session-id: b00db39f948d13ea1e59b4d6fce56389" https://{api_host}/api/appliance/system/version
```

Here is the error:

```json
{
    "error_type": "NOT_FOUND",
    "messages": [
        {
            "args": [],
            "default_message": "Not found.",
            "id": "com.vmware.vapi.rest.httpNotFound"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of vSphere you're using, there was a bug in the REST API that would cause a very similar error (though, I'm fairly positive the error result was "not authenticated" instead of "not found"). A workaround was to restart the vAPI service, or in some cases rebooting the entire vCenter appliance. The fix was introduced in 6.7U3 and 7.0U1, I believe.